# When to pronounce # for pound, sharp, hash or hashtag?

Tags: pronunciation, word-usage, typography, symbols

How to pronounce `#` in a proper way?

Currently, I know it's used to pronounce "pound" in US English, "hash" in British English, "sharp" for C#--a programming language, and number sign to list items. Not sure if I'm right or not.

Also, I lives in non-English speaking country and many pronounce "hashtag" for this symbol, though I'm suspicious about this.

I'd be glad if you can list more examples about this.

-

Update: To be clear: The question is about the pronunciation, not how it came from.

Comment: I think this may not necessarily answer your question thoroughly, but check [this blog post](http://blog.dictionary.com/octothorpe/) by Dictionary.com out.

Comment: Thanks Rex. It discovers some stories and reminds me the music sign of #. It did help!

Comment: The OP knows and accepts four definitions, and is "suspicious" about a fifth.  Doesn't sound as if he has a problem with multiple definitions.

Comment: As for how you describe this symbol by itself (in AmE) for the various contexts:  _pound sign, number sign, sharp,_and _hash mark_ (except when it's _hashtag_.)

Comment: Thanks BrianHitchcock. For @tchrist, I don't know when to pronounce the correct one so I just asked if there's an answer did exist.

Comment: I've called it "octothorpe" since college in the 70s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the symbol in AT&T patent filings is "octothorp," but no one ever says this.  If it precedes a number, say "number" as in "#2 pencils."  If you're talking about a telephone key pad or if it follows a number say "pound" or "hash" (if you are using US or UK English respectively) as in "enter your password followed by the # sign" or "a 5# bag of sugar."  If it's in a tweet say "hashtag."

For speculations on whether # symbol is called "pound" because it replaced the £ symbol in telegraphy and telephony I recommend the following:  [language log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2461)

Comment: I like the examples you used, and it's pretty clear with that. Thanks!

Comment: Very likely that # was called "pound" before it appeared on the typewriter because the shift key wasn't introduced until after ITA 1 was in use in the US.

Comment: The name "octothorp" was originally a joke, played by some AT&T technical employees, that got loose in the world. (And the pranksters didn't say anything until—I believe—they had retired and couldn't suffer any consequences.) You can find the story, told by one of the instigators of the prank, somewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

In Britain it's generally pronounced hash, and in America I believe generally pound. Pound in Britain more commonly refers to the currency. Pronunciation varies depending on the context.

In a tweet it would be pronounced hashtag as is "Off to the bake shop #buyingsomecake" which would be pronounced "Off to the bake shop, hashtag buying some cake"

In musical notation it would be pronounced sharp, as in "Can you play that in the key of F#" - "can you play that in the key of eff sharp"